# Index Conversion of multidimensional array in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, c++14

I have sample code which converts 3d coordinate to id(index) and reverse.
How can i do this for N Dimentional(for example 5d and 6d) array?
here is the 3d conversion code :

```
inline NoximCoord id2Coord(int id) {
  NoximCoord coord;

  coord.z = id / (NoximGlobalParams::mesh_dim_x *
                  NoximGlobalParams::mesh_dim_y);  ////
  coord.y = (id - coord.z * NoximGlobalParams::mesh_dim_x *
                      NoximGlobalParams::mesh_dim_y) /
            NoximGlobalParams::mesh_dim_x;
  coord.x = (id - coord.z * NoximGlobalParams::mesh_dim_x *
                      NoximGlobalParams::mesh_dim_y) %
            NoximGlobalParams::mesh_dim_x;

  assert(coord.x < NoximGlobalParams::mesh_dim_x);
  assert(coord.y < NoximGlobalParams::mesh_dim_y);
  assert(coord.z < NoximGlobalParams::mesh_dim_z);

  return coord;
}

inline int coord2Id(const NoximCoord &coord) {
  int id =
      coord.z * NoximGlobalParams::mesh_dim_x * NoximGlobalParams::mesh_dim_y +
      (coord.y * NoximGlobalParams::mesh_dim_x) + coord.x;
  assert(id < NoximGlobalParams::mesh_dim_x * NoximGlobalParams::mesh_dim_y *
                  NoximGlobalParams::mesh_dim_z);
  return id;
}
```

I need the conversion in this way (c++ <14)not the ways implemented on other answers.

Comment: I would replace `x`, `y` and `z` in `coord` and `mesh_dim` with index `0`-`2` and look for a pattern. You need a loop for all dimensions and a loop in each dimension to calculate the value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, this is pretty standard from what I can tell. The coordinate to ID transformation is a simple polynomial evaluation which is best evaluated using [Horner's method](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Horner%27s_method&oldid=1122788594). The inverse looks more confusing than it needs to be simply because you are inconsistent in using modulo or manually computing it.

Here is a version that uses `std::arrays` for its dimensions, going from inner most dimension to outermost, so `{x, y, z, ...}`

```cpp
#include <array>
#include <functional>
// using std::multiplies
#include <numeric>
// using std::partial_sum


template<std::size_t N>
int coord2Id(const std::array<int, N>& coords,
             const std::array<int, N>& mesh) noexcept
{
    int id = coords.back();
    for(std::size_t i = N - 1; i > 0; --i)
        id = id * mesh[i - 1] + coords[i - 1];
    return id;
}

template<std::size_t N>
std::array<int, N> id2Coord(int id, const std::array<int, N>& mesh) noexcept
{
    std::array<int, N> coord;
    std::array<int, N-1> partials;
    std::partial_sum(mesh.begin(), mesh.end() - 1, partials.begin(),
                     std::multiplies<int>{});
    for(std::size_t i = N - 1; i > 0; --i) {
        coord[i] = id / partials[i - 1];
        id = id % partials[i - 1];
    }
    coord.front() = id;
    return coord;
}
```

A word of warning: For large dimensions, ID can easily overflow the integer range, for example a `{500, 500, 500, 500}` mesh would already be too large. I suggest switching to `std::ptrdiff_t` instead.

Here is a quick conversion from the original pattern:

```cpp
class NoximCoord
{
public:
    int x, y, z;
};
struct NoximGlobalParams
{
    static int mesh_dim_x, mesh_dim_y, mesh_dim_z;
};
int coord2Id(const NoximCoord& coord) noexcept
{
    return coord2Id(std::array<int, 3>{{coord.x, coord.y, coord.z}},
        std::array<int, 3>{{NoximGlobalParams::mesh_dim_x,
                            NoximGlobalParams::mesh_dim_y,
                            NoximGlobalParams::mesh_dim_z}});
}
NoximCoord id2Coord(int id) noexcept
{
    std::array<int, 3> coords = id2Coord(
        id, std::array<int, 3>{{NoximGlobalParams::mesh_dim_x,
                                NoximGlobalParams::mesh_dim_y,
                                NoximGlobalParams::mesh_dim_z}});
    return NoximCoord{coords[0], coords[1], coords[2]};
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer, since my NoximCoord is a class like :
```
class NoximCoord {
 public:
  int x;  // X coordinate
  int y;  // Y coordinate
  int z;  // Z coordinate
  inline bool operator==(const NoximCoord &coord) const {
    return (coord.x == x && coord.y == y && coord.z == z);
  }
};
```
can you give me an example how to use your code?